# How to change the divider height of listview dynamically?

Tags: android, listview, height, dynamic, divider

I have a listview in which there should be different divider height
between different rows. So, how can we set the divider height
dynamically?

Suppose, I have 10 rows and there should be a divider height of 5
between first 2 rows and then there should be a divider height of 1
between next 5 rows and so on.

Can someone let me know the way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to make the dividers rows.  Set them as not enabled in your `isEnabled` adapter method.  I do that for section headers, but it is almost the same thing.  Another way would be to manually lay out your whole list by implementing onLayout.  If the dividers can be empty space, it might work to set top or bottom margins for the root view of your rows.  In xml that would be:

```
    android:layout_marginTop='5px'
```

Otherwise, just make the dividers part of the rows.

Comment: I don't understand how can one include divider as part of the row. I have a background image for the row. If I include the divider as part of the row then that would be included within that image itself. I will like to have that image below the row image. How can one do this?

Comment: Each row can be a ViewGroup with any number of child views.  One of those child views could be the divider image.  It would mean using different types of rows for different size dividers.

Comment: Can you give me some example with show how to do it? Do you actually mean to place divider in the row xml file or have the different xml file for divider. Please let me know.

Comment: Place the divider in the row xml for rows that have a larger divider.  You could have several different row layouts, or edit each row as it is created.

Comment: Yes, the list divider needs to be empty space i.e it will reflect the background color of the screen. Can you please let me know how to do this? I am really very clueless in this.

Comment: I used the suggestion of creating different xml files for rows with dividers and ones without, then in getView of adapter I inflated which one I wanted based on position. Worked great.

Comment: HOWEVER, be aware when using different layouts of different heights, the listview's height will be determined by the first row that is inflated. So for example if your first row that is inflated is not as tall as other rows, then your overall listview height won't be tall enough to accomodate all rows. I'm still unsure how to fix this issue.