# Android Listview - varying dividerHeight between items

Tags: android, listview, spacing

is it possible to have a listview with different values for the android:dividerHeight-attribute between items?
For example like this:

```
listitem 
listitem
listitem

listitem 
listitem 
listitem 

listitem 
listitem 
listitem
```

Comment: Umh.. u can also set blank views to add spaces among them.. :)

Comment: Have a look at this [answer][1], it should work for you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858180/change-the-divider-height-of-listview-dynamically

Comment: You can make custom layout for this by giving top margin

Answer (score 1):

You can add the divider into your listitem and set visibility between `GONE` and `VISIBLE`.

Or you can try another approach playing with sections: http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/07/05/listview-tips-tricks-2-section-your-listview/

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. What you want is achievable with a custom adapter, overriding also

`getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()`