# Space in a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview and I want to change the dividerHeight for specific Item.

For example I want it look like that:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3

// Bigger space here

Item 4
Item 5
```

I know how to change space between each Items but how can I specify a space depending on the item position in the list.
The other possibility is to use a different drawer for some items.

Thanks a lot

PS: Sorry for my bad english, I'm french

EDIT: Here is the code where my Items are displayed on my Listview:

```
    drawerItemsList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);
    myDrawer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_drawer);

    myDrawer.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_item, drawerItemsList));
```

Comment: maybe you can change in getView(), it also bases on position.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my post with the code. I don't know how i can use getView() in this code.

Comment: you are working with ArrayAdapter, you should create a class extends ArrayAdapter. In this class, override getView() to custom the view of each row (item). It means, firstly, you need to study how custom adapter of list view.
About setting dividerHeight, you cannot apply for each item, it only applies for whole listview. You can refer alter solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858180/change-the-divider-height-of-listview-dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize your adapter by extending `ArrayAdapter` class and then do what you want in its `getView` method, A simple solution for your problem might be the following snippet code:

```
@Override
protected View getView(int position, View convertView, AdapterView parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    // Check 'view' value and inflate it if needed

    if(position == 3) { // Gap index in the list
        // Here you can add some additional bottom margin or padding to the
        // 'view'.
        // Or you can left this view empty like a free space
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I tried what you said but when I whrite "View view = convertView" I have an error on the @override which said: method does not override method from its superclass

Comment: @Tartempion34 I'm not certain about the override!, just delete it `:)`

Comment: It didn't work anymore so I changed the extends. Now my class extends baseAdapter and it works fine. Thanks for your help